# How to disable language extension in VC++ when creating a DLL?

Tags: c++, dll

I am having trouble creating a DLL in VC++. I do not want to use language extensions to have portable code. However, the default use of stdafx.h seems to require the language extensions.

I am trying to rewrite dllmain.cpp to remove the dependency to stdafx.h. I first removed the use of precompiled headers. I still get the same compile error:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\driverspecs.h(142): error C2008: '$' : unexpected in macro definition
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\driverspecs.h(294): error C2008: '$' : unexpected in macro definition
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\driverspecs.h(295): warning C4005: '__' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\driverspecs.h(142) : see previous definition of '__'
```

So far my dllmain.cpp looks like this:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "WTypes.h"

#define DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH   1    
#define DLL_THREAD_ATTACH    2    
#define DLL_THREAD_DETACH    3    
#define DLL_PROCESS_DETACH   0    
typedef void far            *LPVOID;

int WINAPI DllMain( HINSTANCE hModule,
                       int  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Am I using the right approach here? Can I get rid of the last dependency (HINSTANCE) on WTypes.h?

Many thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to make an OS-specific DLL entry point portable?

Comment: Well I would like the rest of the code to be portable, which is why I deactivated language extensions... Maybe not the right way to do it?

Comment: There will be specific code for a Windows DLL vs. a Linux dynamic library and that's unavoidable.  Isolate those specific pieces of code and allow them to use the OS-specific features, but keep the bulk of your code portable.

Comment: For that matter, if your above code is all that is in dllmain.cpp, you can just delete it.  You don't have to provide a DllMain if it doesn't do anything.

Comment: That sounds good to me... I thought it was compulsory as created by default by VC++. Many thanks!

Comment: Nope, it is just boilerplate.  You can right-click, Remove, select Delete on the dllmain.cpp and everything still works.  Same goes for stdafx.cpp/h if you don't want them, although you have to take the `#include "stdafx.h"` out of the source files and set the project to "Do not use precompiled headers".

Comment: `"stdafx.h"`, while a Microsoft idiom, can certainly compile on other systems, _provided that it lists only standard headers_. E.g. `<vector>` is OK, `<windows.h>` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the DLL entry function generated by Visual Studio C++ would not be modified in any way since it contains the basics for allowing the Windows Operating System to load the DLL into memory and initialize it.

Everything that I have read says that the DLLMain() should do as little as possible including initialization in order to avoid serious problems with Windows loading the DLL and initializing everything needed to make the various DLL entry points available.

You will notice that there is lots of Windows API stuff and defines and little else.

So if you make the rest of your DLL methods, which are normally in other source files portable, you may be able to rip out the DLL main, put whatever OS specific dynamic load initialization you are wanting to port to in place of it and keep the rest of your source.

The DLLMain is really just a place to have Windows OS specific entry points that Windows needs to load your DLL and correct the various function offsets and addresses.

Also see this [MSDN article on DLLMain()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

And this [DLL tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dll/dll_writing.htm).

And see this [caution on modifying DLLMain()](http://www.voyce.com/index.php/2009/12/03/dont-do-anything-in-dllmain-please/).

Comment: Thanks Richard, I understand that the DLLMain is not compulsory; is there any drawback in not having it, in cases where it does not do anything at all?

Comment: @GL770, I personally have spent too much time trying to debug something non-standard so that these days I treat Visual Studio like I treat my wife.  I just say Yes Dear and do what I am told unless there  is really a good reason to do otherwise.  It does not hurt to keep the boilerplate and it might be useful at a later time so I just keep it in and try not to mess with it.